# how to reopen a activity in notification click i android

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications

I am working on a application where user can login in the login activity. And a logged in user can see their review in dashboard activity. And if any new review is coming in server it will push a notification. Everything is running perfect Except one thing i.e. when user click on the notification, it is opening a new dashboard activity every time if the dashboard activity is in front then also.

What i am wanting is that if user click on the notification it will open dashboard activity only when application is not running. otherwise if the dashboard activity is in front then if user will click on it , it will first close the dashboard activity and the it will reopen the activity page.
Here is the code i am written to go the dashboard activity.

```
    Intent startActivityIntent = new Intent(this, DashboardActivity.class); 
    startActivityIntent.putExtra("NotificationMessage", service_notification);
    startActivityIntent.putExtra("flag", 1);
    startActivityIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
    PendingIntent launchIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            startActivityIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    earthquakeNotificationBuilder
                .setContentIntent(launchIntent)
                .setContentTitle(no_of_review + " " + "new review is there")
                .setAutoCancel(true);
```

I have tried many thing but didn't get a solution. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

and the `android:launchMode="singleTask"` in your androidmanifest.xml so you can andd `android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true`

```
        <activity
            android:name=".DashboardActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: i have changed this. But if dashboard activity is open nothing happens. What i am wanting is that if dashboard activity already opened then if i click on notification it will first close it then re-open it.

Comment: what is the flag i should pass with the intent instead of this(startActivityIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );)

Comment: I think default flag should be OK.You don't need to pass any other flag manually.

Answer (score 1):

**THIS CODE WILL reopen a activity if open,otherwise app will start again**

```
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> tasks = am.getRunningTasks(1);
        ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo task = tasks.get(0); // get current task
        ComponentName rootActivity = task.baseActivity;

        Intent notificationIntent;
        if(rootActivity.getPackageName().equalsIgnoreCase("your package name")){
            //your app is open
            // Now build an Intent that will bring this task to the front
             notificationIntent = new Intent();
            notificationIntent.setComponent(rootActivity);
            notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);

        }
        else
        {
//your app is not open,start it by calling launcher activity
             notificationIntent = new Intent(context, SplashActivity.class);


        }
        notificationIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        notificationIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
         notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);





        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                notificationIntent, 0);

//use this pending intent in notification..
```

see complete example [HERE](http://shortcutsandroid.blogspot.in/2015/02/reopen-activity-on-notification-click.html) ..

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is that you are creating a new activity every time the user clicks the notification. Now the thing you have to do is add this FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP to your intent and also change **launchmode** of your activity in **ManifestFile**. Also Override **OnNewIntent()** Method in your **DashboardActivity**

Here is some Code to help you

```
startActivityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

And Change your ManifestFile like this

```
 <activity 
  android:name=".DashboardActivity"
  android:launchMode="singleTop">
 </activity>
```

Then Override OnNewIntent Method in your DashBoard Activity like this

```
@Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {

        DashboardActivity.this.finish();

        // -----Start New Dashboard  when notification is clicked----

        Intent i = new Intent(DashboardActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class);

        startActivity(i);

        super.onNewIntent(intent);
    }
```

The OnNewIntent method will fire whenever your activity exists and notification is clicked

Also study [launchmodes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) if you want your activities to behave differently in different situations.

Comment: i have changed this. But if dashboard activity is open nothing happens. What i am wanting is that if dashboard activity already opened then if i click on notification it will first close it then re-open it.

Comment: @Andu Now check it i have changed the answer. It should work like you want it too

Comment: should i call onNewIntent(intent) method from onCreate method?

Comment: Actually now it is opening perfect. But one problem still there is that if i will click on notification and if it comes to the activity then a time will change. and it will send to json And through json it will check is there any new review after that time is or not. But what is happening when i am clicking on notification it is changing the time after entering in the new activity but still it shows the old notification. it is going away after second click. Can you tell me what is going wrong?

Comment: @Andru what do u mean by this ? "when i am clicking on notification it is changing the time after entering in the new activity but still it shows the old notification"

Please explain in More Detail

Comment: How can I use this code when I need to add a putextra when notification is clicked ?

Comment: @AmarIlindra just use `getExtra()` in `onNewIntent()` to get the parameters that you extras that you passed.