# Trying to restore state of activity upon starting it via a notification

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-webview, android-notifications

I am implementing a webview loading the URL of an web-application that dynamically adds content to the DOM based on user-action via a socket.
As I am closing the App and a user adds another element in the web-application the app-user gets a notification.
If I re-open the App via manually starting it again, I can easily restore the webview and see the new content as well.
My problem: I want to achieve the same when re-opening the App via the notification. Currently I do not get savedInstanceState in onCreate().

launchMode is set to singleTop

Code in WebAppInterface.java:

```
System.out.println("WebAppInterface:" + MainActivity.MY_ACTIVITY_STATUS);
    if (!MainActivity.MY_ACTIVITY_STATUS) {
        Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Neue Nachricht")
            .setContentText(username + " hat dir geschrieben!")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(alarmSound)
            .setVibrate(new long[] { 0, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 });

        // The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
        // started Activity.
        // This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
        // your application to the Home screen.
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(mContext);
        // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
        // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
        Intent intent= new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, intent, 0);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        // Sets an ID for the notification
        int mNotificationId = 001;

        // Gets an instance of the NotificationManager service
        NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // Builds the notification and issues it.
        mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
```

Code for restoring in my MainActivity:

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        myWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    } else {
        myWebView.loadUrl(URL_TO_WEB_APP);
    }
```

So far I'Ve testes various combinations of Intent.FLAGS/launchMode as well as saving savedInstanceState to a private static variable and trying to restore the webview based on this variable (getting tons of "nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color." in LogCat).

Upon starting the App via notification:
  private static variable "myWebView" (in which I store the webview) is set
  onCreate() parameter Bundle savedInstanceState is null
  private static variable "savedState" (above mentioned attempt to safe savedInstanceState and use it) is set

I'd be happy for every hint and/or even a solution, as I am currently completely clueless.

Comment: It seems this guys had exactly the same problem and solved it! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16229596/how-to-reopen-a-activity-in-notification-click-i-android

Comment: @eduyayo Unfortuantely on the contrary, he wants to close the task of the activity first and then reopen it. I attempt to restore the last state of my activity

Comment: noope... read it, please... wants to reuse the opened activity!

Comment: @eduyayo still reads the opposite way to me, but I tested it - unfortunately with no working result. As I do not have access to savedInstanceState I cannot restore the state of the webview.

Comment: have you tested it with `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` as the last parameter of `PendingIntent.getActivity`??

Comment: I´ve got an app with notifications and I reopen the main activity with similar code... should work :(

Comment: @eduyayo With FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT neither :/ But just to be sure we aren't talking about different things: Opening the activity is not a problem, I got this going for a while now. Restoring the state of the webview is what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I'm sure I had this combination tested dozens of times, the working combination - in order to restore the state of the WebView - is:
In WebAppInterface.java:

```
        Intent intent= new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, intent, 0);
```

In AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <activity
        ...
        android:launchMode="singleTask" >
```

Furthermode there was no code needed for onResume()/onNewIntent() in the MainActivity.